# malloc errors when passing around cv:Mat references

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2's cv::Mat structures for several objects in a game. Sometimes these are passed around directly, sometimes by a `cv::Mat*` pointer, such as when one object needs to modify another object's cv::Mat. I am used to having to manage memory myself, but I understand that cv::Mat uses reference counting. Everything seems to work most of the time, however occasionally I get the following error running in debug mode in Xcode:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x3000000000000000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

This occurs when I pass two cv::Mats to a function, as below:

```
Find(this->fillShape, shape->fillShape)
```

This error does not occur every time I run across this line though. How shall I debug this?

Comment: Are you trying call `free()` inside this function without do `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` before?

Comment: I am not calling any of those myself. If they are, OpenCV is calling them.

Answer (score 0):

From section 7.20.3.2 The free function of C99 standard:

```
The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.
```

My suggestion for debugging this would be to read the open cv documentation and ensure you are properly allocating the memory in each Matrix. Internal to cv::Mat's is a 'header' and a pointer to allocated memory where actual data is stored. The 'header' is created when you declare a matrix, but a distinct call to the object, whether its a copy or allocation, is required to allocate the memory the Mat points to. The issue is probably a result of not allocating the internal memory before the reference count drops below zero and the destructor is called but I don't have a ton of experience with cv::Mat's desctructor. You should look at the first code example here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html